# Lerna Jenkins setup

Tags: jenkins, lerna

Setting up a Lerna mono-repo with a jenkins deploy file. Whats the general approach for deploying only packages that have changed? And how do I handle a scenario where specific packages might require different build scripts. For example some may need to be published to an NPM repo, and others may need to be deployed as a service.

Do I need to have a loop inside my Jenkins file that iterates through every changed package and handles it that way?  Appreciate any guidance <3